# How to imitate PaddingTop with Grid Material UI and fill empty rows from the top?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Suppose we have the Grid

```
const App = () => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: "center",
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can we imitate PaddingTop and add empty rows from the top using Grid ?

Comment: @keikai: I can't see how

Answer (score 0):

You can acquire the space using `spacing={10}` in the top `Grid container` to adjust.

Also, you can add a new Grid with `xs={12}` if you want something to show.

---

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Grid, makeStyles, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
export default (App = () => {
  const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
      flexGrow: 1
    },
    paper: {
      padding: theme.spacing(2),
      textAlign: "center",
      color: theme.palette.text.secondary
    }
  }));
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={8}>
          <Grid container spacing={3}>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=12 sm=6</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6} sm={3}>
              <Paper className={classes.paper}>xs=6 sm=3</Paper>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={4}>
          <Grid item xs={12} />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
});
```

[image: Edit unruffled-dewdney-2uvk7]

Comment: Thanks , but I don't need another element , the purpose is a Padding-Top look alike.

Comment: Yeah, you can remove the `<Paper />`, and only use the spacing to make that adjustment, online demo has been updated